# Application Request Routing reverse proxy not forwarding X-ARR-ClientCert header

Tags: iis, arr

I have IIS ARR set up as a reverse proxy with a web app sitting behind it. If I send a HTTPS request to the proxy with a value in the `X-ARR-ClientCert` header then that value won't reach the web app. How can this be fixed?

I've set SSL Settings to accept client certificates. As per [this guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/01/27/configuring-arr-with-client-certificate/) I also changed the `system.webServer/proxy` configuration field to be something else then `X-ARR-ClientCert` without success.

The proxy passes any other header through properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X-ARR-ClientCert is sent if there was a mutual SSL handshake with ARR. Sending a request via https with the X-ARR-ClientCert header won't be enough as there really wasn't a mutual SSL handshake in that scenario. By a mutual SSL handshake, It means that the browser or client gets prompted for a client certificate and the client provides one.

If you want your setup to work with the X-ARR-ClientCert header, I'd recommend to install [ARR Helper](http://blogs.iis.net/anilr/client-ip-not-logged-on-content-server-when-using-arr). One of its features is that it reads the X-ARR-ClientCert header (configurable to be any arbitrary header with a base64 encoded certificate) and it emulates the requests to have the client certificate.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and also for the link. So if I understand correctly the X-ARR-ClientCert header (or whatever is configured) will contain the client certificate in the app behind the proxy if the proxy completed the mutual SSL handshake. Right?

Comment: Basically: yes. Sending the X-ARR-ClientCert header does not constitute a mutual SSL Handshake. A mutual SSL handshake takes place when at the SSL handshake level a certreq is sent to the client, usually resulting in a prompt for a certificate when the client is a browser. However, since ARR Helper is capable of reading and parsing the X-ARR-ClientCert header and reinsert it back on the HttpRequest class, it may be worth trying to install ARR Helper to see if it successfully receives the X-ARR-ClientCert header and forward it from there to your backend servers using the same header.